# Watch dogs Crash on loading screen

Tags: pc, watch-dogs

Watch dogs crashes after clicking "New Game". I have the latest drivers from Nvidia, and have tried to verify files on Uplay ( i have done everything i could find on google).

*Crash report:* "A program has caused the program to stop working"

**My computer specs**
GPU: Asus GTX 770 2 way SLI
CPU: i7-4770K Haswell
Ram: 8 GB
Resolution: 1920x1080

Comment: Is there an error message or anything or is this just a crash to desktop with no notification?

Comment: We will need more then what you have provided.  I can confirm on a nearly identical setup Watch Dogs has no problem which means its likely a configuration problem on your end.

Comment: does it work if you disable SLI? I've always had problems with it.

Comment: It just says Watch Dogs has stopped working "close program"

i want to play with SLI...

Comment: how do i disable SLI?